# Let $\gamma: L_1 \rightarrow L_2$ be a surjective morphism of Lie Algebras....

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-algebras

Let $\gamma: L_1 \rightarrow L_2$ be a surjective morphism of Lie Algebras. If $h \in L_1$ and $ad(h)$ are diagonalizable, does this mean that $ad(\gamma(h))$ is diagonalizable? I've been trying to prove that it is, and I've been unsuccessful, so I tried looking for a counter example but alas my mathematical skills are lacking in general. I could really use some help on this one...

I appreciate the help, alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so. Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be an eigenbasis in $L_1$ of $ad(h)$. Note that certainly, $\gamma(e_1),\dots,\gamma(e_n)$ spans $L_2$ for $\gamma$ is surjective. Lastly, one can find a maximally linearly independent subset from $\gamma(e_1),\dots,\gamma(e_n)$ which is a basis for $L_2$ and it is easy to see that this is an eigenbasis for $ad(\gamma(h))$ since

$$[\gamma(h), \gamma(e_i)]= \gamma([h,e_i]) = \gamma(ce_i) = c\gamma(e_i)$$